# Where in Visual Studio 2012 C++ nanosleep() gone?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Where in Visual Studio 2012 nanosleep() gone? What include i need to add to get the nanosleep(), or what is the best way to make a delay in miliseconds in C++ Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Seems to me that `nanosleep` is POSIX. It's certainly not required for standard C or standard C++.

Comment: Since `nanosleep` is a POSIX function, I'd guess that it's not "gone", as it was never actually there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this, which is portable, Standard C++11 code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

// ...

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
```

Alternatively, you could use the Windows API [`Sleep()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (declared in the `WinBase.h` Windows header):

```
::Sleep(1000);
```